# Getting TypeError doing bundle exec rake, but shouldn't be?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am updating my app in production, and after doing `git pull` and:

```
bundle install --deployment --without development test
```

I did:

```
bundle exec rake assets:precompile db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production --trace
```

and got an error:

```
test_app@mywebsite:/var/www/test_app/code$ bundle exec rake assets:precompile db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production --trace
** Invoke assets:precompile (first_time)
** Invoke assets:environment (first_time)
** Execute assets:environment
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
rake aborted!
TypeError: no implicit conversion of Fixnum into String
/var/www/test_app/code/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/key_generator.rb:21:in `pbkdf2_hmac_sha1'
/var/www/test_app/code/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/key_generator.rb:21:in `generate_key'
/var/www/test_app/code/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/key_generator.rb:38:in `generate_key'
/var/www/test_app/code/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/globalid-0.4.1/lib/global_id/railtie.rb:26:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
/var/www/test_app/code/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `execute_hook'
/var/www/test_app/code/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:45:in `block in run_load_hooks'
/var/www/test_app/code/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `each'
/var/www/test_app/code/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `run_load_hooks'
/var/www/test_app/code/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:62:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
/var/www/test_app/code/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/var/www/test_app/code/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/var/www/test_app/code/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.4/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.4/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.4/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.4/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.4/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.4/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.4/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.4/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.4/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
/var/www/test_app/code/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
/var/www/test_app/code/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
/var/www/test_app/code/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/var/www/test_app/code/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/application.rb:328:in `require'
/var/www/test_app/code/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/application.rb:328:in `require_environment!'
/var/www/test_app/code/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/application.rb:457:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
/var/www/test_app/code/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/task.rb:251:in `block in execute'
/var/www/test_app/code/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/task.rb:251:in `each'
/var/www/test_app/code/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/task.rb:251:in `execute'
/var/www/test_app/code/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/task.rb:195:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.4/lib/ruby/2.3.0/monitor.rb:214:in `mon_synchronize'
/var/www/test_app/code/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/task.rb:188:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/var/www/test_app/code/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/task.rb:181:in `invoke'
/var/www/test_app/code/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.1/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:62:in `block (2 levels) in define'
/var/www/test_app/code/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/task.rb:251:in `block in execute'
/var/www/test_app/code/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/task.rb:251:in `each'
/var/www/test_app/code/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/task.rb:251:in `execute'
/var/www/test_app/code/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/task.rb:195:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.4/lib/ruby/2.3.0/monitor.rb:214:in `mon_synchronize'
/var/www/test_app/code/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/task.rb:188:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/var/www/test_app/code/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/task.rb:217:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
/var/www/test_app/code/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/task.rb:215:in `each'
/var/www/test_app/code/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/task.rb:215:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/var/www/test_app/code/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/task.rb:194:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.4/lib/ruby/2.3.0/monitor.rb:214:in `mon_synchronize'
/var/www/test_app/code/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/task.rb:188:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/var/www/test_app/code/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/task.rb:181:in `invoke'
/var/www/test_app/code/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `invoke_task'
/var/www/test_app/code/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/var/www/test_app/code/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `each'
/var/www/test_app/code/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `block in top_level'
/var/www/test_app/code/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:125:in `run_with_threads'
/var/www/test_app/code/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:110:in `top_level'
/var/www/test_app/code/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:83:in `block in run'
/var/www/test_app/code/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'
/var/www/test_app/code/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:80:in `run'
/var/www/test_app/code/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/var/www/test_app/code/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/bin/rake:22:in `load'
/var/www/test_app/code/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/bin/rake:22:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:75:in `load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:75:in `kernel_load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:28:in `run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/cli.rb:424:in `exec'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/cli.rb:27:in `dispatch'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:466:in `start'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/cli.rb:18:in `start'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/bundler-1.16.1/exe/bundle:30:in `block in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:122:in `with_friendly_errors'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/bundler-1.16.1/exe/bundle:22:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/bin/bundle:22:in `load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/bin/bundle:22:in `<main>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => environment
```

The error, `TypeError: no implicit conversion of Fixnum into String` doesn't make sense to me based on my changes.  And even with --trace i'm not seeing any files in the output that correspond with changes I've made. I guess i'm confused about where it is telling me the error is occurring. I made changes to bring the code back how it was before the error, and am still getting the same error when I `bundle exec rake`.

Here are my [github changes](https://github.com/sharperprogrammer/test_app/commits/master) (the last 4 are the change, and 3 attempts to fix), to show how trivial the changes I made that started giving me this error were.

In case it matters, running my app on Ubuntu 16.04, Nginx 1.12.2 proxy => Apache 2.4.18 + Passenger 5.2.0.

Edit: I know that there is no issue with the code, as I have cleanly deployed this same application to another server, and the `bundle exec rake` executed without error.

Comment: The error started to occur after you added the action mailer config in production.rb right? Did you check your env variables for username and password? Maybe you could try to hardcode them first to see if there`s a different error.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  It was actually one commit later, configuring for SSL.  I changed a number (port number) to another number.  I tried the suggested change, but I got the same error message.  This seems like the type of completely unrelated error that happens when I do something silly (like forget to append bundle exec or something).  Strange.

Comment: Yatta!  What you said inspired me to test more things.  I hard coded the secret key for my app, and now my rake tasks work!  Interesting error for such a thing.  I'll have to go have a google and find out how to setup ENV variables so that they are always setup correctly.  Thank you very much Forlani!

Comment: You are welcome! These environment variables always tricky to me